# How do you test if two external values are equal in a mongodb criteria object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Given a collection:

```
{id: 1, name:"abc"},
{id: 2, name:null}
```

To test a property I use:

```
db.collecton.find({name:"abc"}, {name:1}); // which returns the first document.
```

I want to also add a test for two external values like this:

```
value1 = 100;
value2 = 100; // value2 might be different than value1

db.collecton.find({name:"abc", $eq:[ value1, value2 ]}, {name:1});
```

This results in nothing found.  I don't want to add value1 or value2 as properties, I just want to make sure they match each other in addition to the other criteria.  Also, I realize I could only run the query if the two external values match, but how do you add these external variables into the criteria?

Comment: those value1 and value2 should match against which property?

Comment: Oh, I get it. Like a "run my query only if value1 === value2" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({ name : 'abc', name : { $type : 1 + (value1 === value2) }})
```

Comment: @ChrisGciso yeah I wouldn't actually recommend anyone to use this ;-)

Comment: @ChrisGciso one possible fix could be to use the fact that (usually) the `_id` property is an `ObjectId` ($type value 7).